# OpenID client is failing due to content negotiation on Apache representing OpenID server

Tags: apache-2.2, openid, content-negotiation

*This is a question about configuring Apache and `accept` headers.*

I am trying to login to Superuser with OpenID, and it generates a request like this:

```
telnet phor.net 80
GET /professional HTTP/1.0
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xrds+xml`
```

And my Apache server gives the error:

```
406 Not Acceptable: 
An appropriate representation of the requested resource /professional 
could not be found on this server. Available variants: 
professional.php, type  application/x-httpd-php
```

If a normal web browser hits the site, content negotiation correctly selects professional.php as the resource for this request. Is it possible to serve this same file to superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

```
AddType text/html php
```

In my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding application/x-httpd-php to the accept portion of your request?

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem. But I cannot control the client's (Superuser.com) request, I can only control my server's response.